# Facebook realtime is giving different parent id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

Following is the JSON which i have received from realtime update

> {"id":"this is the page id","time":1390189044,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"comment","verb":"add","comment_id":"10152572606743677_340941814","parent_id":10152572606743676,"sender_id":113833593676,"created_time":1390189044}}]}]}

the weird part is the parent_id is `10152572606743676` and comment_id starts with `10152572606743677` which are totally different and this doesn't happen for all the pages and happens only to a specific pages from facebook

Answer (score 1):

It might be connected with pages having global and localized versions. For this reason the parent id is the global page id and the first part of the comment is the localized version id where the comment is made. Since I can't fetch those IDs it's like shot in the dark but it's worth to check it.

Comment: but how is it possible to have different parent_id i mean the post_id

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but think the idea is that the post has an id on the global page but is replicated for each localized version which raises the need of new post ids. This way each localized post has its own likes, comments, etc. Facebook has really poor documentation on these issues and often people need to guess what's going on :)

Comment: but if there is any localized post at least i should be able to access that post but it is throwing me unsupported get request